# Bypass/prevent slideUp event for child div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here in below code i have a link whose div id is "my-acc-hover-container". When a user hovers on this link a new section will slideDown containing the links as "Hello Guest" and "Login/Sign Up". And when the user clicks on "Login/Sign Up" link a Login popup will appears (named #modal).

```
<div id="my-acc-container-c">
    <a href="#"><h3>Hello Guest !</h3></a>
    <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class=""><h3>Login/Sign Up</h3></a>

    <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
    <!--    LOGIN POPUP -->
    </div>  <!-- end of #modal-->

</div>  <!-- end of #my-acc-container-c-->
```

Here the jQuery is:

```
$('#my-acc-container-c').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#my-acc-hover-container').slideDown(300);
    $('#my-acc-container-c').css("height","200px");
});

$('#my-acc-container-c').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#my-acc-hover-container').slideUp(300);
    $('#my-acc-container-c').css("height","100%");
});
```

But the **problem is** when the user clicks on "Login/Sign Up" link Login Pop Up appears but only for 300ms. As i think this might be because of #modal is a child of #my-acc-hover-container.
So all i want is to display the popup but hiding the #my-acc-hover-container.
Thanks.

Comment: take #modal div out of #my-acc-hover-container. dialog will works.

Comment: I can't find the id `my-acc-container-c` in your code

Comment: Thanks Bhavin Panchani, its solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="my-acc-hover-container">
<a href="#"><h3>Hello Guest !</h3></a>
<a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class=""><h3>Login/Sign Up</h3></a>
</div>  <!-- end of #my-acc-hover-container-->  

<div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
<!--    LOGIN POPUP -->
</div>  <!-- end of #modal-->
```

PFA Snippert. Binding #modal div separately from "my-acc-hover-container" div will work.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/8L7xtojr/2/

Just append the whole content of modal to body

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append($('#modal'));
});
$('#my-acc-container-c').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#my-acc-hover-container').slideDown(300);
    $('#my-acc-container-c').css("height","200px");
});

$('#my-acc-container-c').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#my-acc-hover-container').slideUp(300);
    $('#my-acc-container-c').css("height","100%");
});
```

Although the pop us is not opening in fiddle but the content is being replaced from inside to the last of body. You can check it by inspect element.